# My windows phone doesn't allow me to select a file to upload from the browser

Tags: 7.x, internet-explorer

When I go to any website in my WP7 browser and this website has a "browse" button, when I press on this button nothing happens. (I'm not sure if this happened after the update from IE7 to IE9 or if it was like that before.)

Is this a common issue? How can I solve it?

Comment: @Tom Wimdows Phone 7.0 ran IE7 mobile, WP 7.5 runs IE9 mobile

Comment: @RichardSzalay: Thanks, didn't know that. cc@AmrElgarhy: Sorry, missed the title, I understand now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

File upload functions in browsers assume you have full access to the file system.  With WP you do not have unfettered access to the file system on the phone.  Therefore, until IE9 allows you to choose from the locations on the phone where you *do* have access, this isn't possible.  Perhaps in IE10?  Those details aren't released yet IIRC.

Answer (score 5):

This is a limitation of the operating system and is similar to other mobile platforms. Because the concept of a universal file system doesn't exist, there is nowhere to choose a file from to upload.

Comment: I'm doubting about the technical accuracy of your second sentence, because applications do have their own data store as well as the various hubs. Theorectically, the Photo / Video / Music hubs would be valid places to choose a file from. I think it's rather a matter of support than the non-existence of space. It might have been done to simplify things, though...

Comment: I think upload button in works in Android. Should work in WP7. Bring the Picture hub is enought to me.

Comment: It is actually supported on recent versions of most mobile platforms now: http://viljamis.com/blog/2012/file-upload-support-on-mobile/

Comment: What is the solution? Please give me a direct answer if this bug has been solved or not... If solved,please explain me how..

Comment: For Windows Phone 7 & 8, this has still not been fixed. For newer versions of Android and iOS it will work with some limitations.

Answer (score 3):

The file upload capabilities have been extended with IE11 on WP 8.1, now allowing you to upload photos, videos, documents, music, ringtones and downloaded files.

http://ryanjoy.com/2014/04/file-upload-in-ie11-on-windows-phone-8-1/