# FTP client in Windows Phone 7.8 or Windows Phone 8

Tags: 8.0, 7.8, file-transfer, ftp

Uploading and downloading files is quite a necessity for me. Since at most times, a very minor editing is required, so having an application on mobile will ease the process a lot.

I have a Nokia Lumia 710 which runs on Windows phone 7.8 OS and I searched for such an applcation in marketplace, but couldn't find one.

Do you know any FTP solution that allows downloading/uploading along with text editing or Windows phone just doesn't support it?

Incase, WP 7.8 doesn't support this, which mobile OS does??

Comment: Have you tried Microsoft Cloud services, such as SkyDrive and/or Office apps?

Comment: @GregC I am talking in hosting server prespective. Talking about the code editing for my my website.

Comment: There's a lot of web-based FTP clients available. Would using one with IE work?

Comment: @Bob ya sure as long as i am able to download and upload files

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay Scratch that idea. [net2ftp](http://net2ftp.com) works for an online editor, but download wouldn't let me open a file and upload [wouldn't work at all](http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/21/1592) on my 520. Unless you manage to find a different browser, you won't have much luck there.

Comment: @Bob hmm....k....

Answer (score 2):

A quick search of the Marketplace yielded two results:

1. [Ftp On The Go: available for $4.99 and rated 3/5](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ftp-on-the-go/803fc8f1-5551-4372-aa97-4207a95144b7)
2. [My FTP: available for $1.29 and rated 1.5/5](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/ftp-on-the-go/803fc8f1-5551-4372-aa97-4207a95144b7)

You can check out the reviews for both of the above to see which better suits your needs.

Both of the above solutions allow you to download and upload files from a remote server to your phone. To be able to edit files and assuming that these files can be opened with a text editor, I recommend using [Notepad Free](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/notepad-free/a652eec5-c819-e011-9264-00237de2db9e).

Comment: read the reviews and they weren't supportive. First one does not have directory listing for windows hosting server whereas the second one just isn't impressing. Thanks though :-)